# Parse formatted text from RTF

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

I'm trying to parse lines of bolded text from an RTF file. Right now, I'm sort of doing it by using Regex and looking for the "\b...\b0" tags in the file, but that leaves a lot of formatting text, and there are so many formatting tags in RTF that I can't just hard code it all out and call it a day. Is there a more elegant existing solution for parsing only lines with specific formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an RTF parser... `RichTextBox` comes to mind.  There are several ways of obtaining the formatting using the RTB.

Comment: This answer is now 6 years old.  That said, consult the [RTFBox Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.8).  Specifically the `Selected`* properties.

Answer (score 0):

No. I recently tackled a project in which we had to take an RTF document, complete with embedded media, and convert it to a MIME multipart message. We constructed several sets of RegEx to break apart the sections of the document and then converted each formatting option to an appropriate HTML/CSS tag. There really isn't an "elegant" way to do what you wish.

What are you trying to do with the RTF? Our end-goal was to have a HTML conversion of the RTF supplied. I know that RichTextBox, within the WPF world, has the ability to save out to several formats, such as XAML, which may get rid of the need to handle the parsing yourself.

Also, there are RTF Converters out on the market, so with some more context I could suggest something better.

Comment: I'm trying to take an RTF file and get all the bolded text out of it, separated into lines. Each "line" would be determined as either different sections of bolded text within the same line but separated by non-bolded text, or by any chunk of bolded text that is broken up by line breaks. Ultimately, I want to end up with a List of plain text strings containing each line of text that was bolded in the RTF file.

Comment: Alright, what I have here is a regex pattern that will match for any run that starts with a bold command. Now, I'm not accounting for every case there is. If you want to accept special characters, (!.,{} etc.), you will have to modify your regex or modify how those characters are stored within the RTF. HINT: We changed them out with tokens.

So, here is the regex. Use it to get a list of matches, each being a bold run of characters.
`(?:\{\\b\\ltrch\s)(\w*)(?:\})`

Comment: I messed up! Well, not a huuuge mess up but something that will help. Use this regex and it'll grab anything within the bold text sections:
`(?:\{\\b\\ltrch\s)(.*?)(?:\})`

Comment: It isn't working, and I'm pretty sure I see why. I don't know what program you are using to create the RTF files but I think it follows a different set of RTF standards than mine does. Here's an example of a bold line in my file: 
`{\scaps0\caps0\cf1\expnd0\expndtw0\i0\b\ab\rtlch \ltrch\loch\fs16\loch\f4
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}`
And that kind of illustrates my problem, that I can't foresee what standard whatever RTF file is going to follow. But RichTextBoxes don't seem to have a problem one way or the other, so there must be _something_ out there...

Comment: I see. I was going off of the output of a WPF RichTextBox so I'm getting a simplified RTF. An idea on how to manage this would be to put ORs in your regex. You could OR each set of regex that catches each type of bolded text. So try something like this:
`(?:\{\\b\\ltrch\s)(.*?)(?:\})|(?:\\b[a-zA-Z0-9\\\s]*\\f[0-9]*\s)(.*?)(?:\})`
Then, as you find more ways that the bold text is encoded, you can add more ORs to your regex.

Comment: I've decided to go with the XML-esque output that the WPF RichTextBox is giving me, converting it into an XElement, then just searching for Span nodes with the FontWeight="Bold" attribute. It seems to be working, and running it through the RichTextBox should handle any of the weird standard issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! I'm still stuck in RTF-only as we needed to pull the embedded media as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [RtfDomParser](https://github.com/SourceCodeBackup/RtfDomParser).
I found some cases where the parser does not work but globally it's ok.

Comment: I couldn't understand how to use it, and I found no docs for it.

Comment: I evaluated it and at this time it couldn't read enough formatting to be useful to me.

Comment: I had same problem with RTF documents a "bit too" formatted.